# Python function , parameters, default and then a list

Tags: python-2.7

I want to create a function that has a required parameter, a few default parameters followed by a list of parameters that would vary.

I can get it to work if I use required and a list(*rest)
def getInfo(serial,*rest)
or list only (*rest) 
def getInfo(*rest)
but not with default values(names=0)

```
def getInfo(serial,load=1,name=0, *rest):
    print serial,load,name
    for x in rest:
        print x\n
```

print getInfo(12345,load=2,name=1,1,2,3,4,5)

expecting

```
12345,2,1
1
2
3
4
5
```

Comment: That's against the design of the parameter model of Python: first *unnamed* parameters, then *named* ones.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem would you then recommend changing it to def getInfo(serial,load,name,*rest)